# Why clicking on a 'New Article' in AEM communities does nothing?

Tags: aem, aem-6

I have created a communities site template with page functionalities selected and using that template I have created a new community site. I dropped the blog component from the list but whenever I am clicking on New article, the new blog is not being created. The same is happening with all the other communities components as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Navigate to the page that you have created (ex: /content/community-components/en/journal).
2. Click on jcr:content > content > clientlibslist
3. In the properties add a property scg:requiredClientLibs and add the following values 
   `cq.ckeditor` 
   `cq.social.hbs.voting`
   `cq.social.hbs.journal`
   [image]
4. Refresh the page.